# Xamarin uitest fails to interact with accessibility label for IOS 11.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

Accessibility label of UIView is set to Eg "BackButton"
 [UIAccessibilityBackButtonElement] label: "BackButton"
Xamarin uitest for IOS 11.0 fails to interact with the label
app.Flash("BackButton")                                                     Flashing query for Marked("BackButton") gave 0 results.                         [                                                                                                                                                               ]
I have tried waitForElement, Query methods, etc.Nothing seems to work.
Would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird but marked does not match labels. Here is the description per the method documentation.

Matches common values. For Android: An element with the given value as either id, ***contentDescription*** or text. For iOS: An element with the given value as either ***accessibilityLabel*** or ***accessibilityIdentifier***.

You can find more info via the documentation here, 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Marked/

Here is a post giving more info:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99701/not-able-to-query-label-text-with-property-label

Answer (score 0):

Does your button with this id appear in DOM when you enter 'tree' in REPL?